# How to specify the accuracy/gap of the axis in matplotlib from panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working with longitude and latitude which can be very precise and currently my graph from matplotlib is not capturing that.
Code:

```
HOUSING_PATH = "datasets/housing"
csv_path = os.path.join(HOUSING_PATH, "property5.csv")
housing = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

housing.plot(kind="scatter", x="Longitude", y="Latitude", alpha=0.1)
plt.show()
```

sample data

```
0       153.046109
1       153.045566
2       153.046511
3       153.048725
4       153.045861

Name: Longitude, Length: 8378, dtype: float64
0      -27.457026
1      -27.456798
2      -27.456318
3      -27.456882
4      -27.459056

Name: Latitude, Length: 8378, dtype: float64
```

[image]

How can I graph with the appropriate accuracy in the axis?

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the precision level (number of digits to display after point) using the `set_major_formatter()` function using `FormatStrFormatter` as below....

```
housing.plot(kind="scatter", x="Longitude", y="Latitude", alpha=0.1, figsize=(8, 8))

from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.6f')) #Show 6 digits... plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.6f'))

plt.show()
```

**Graph**

[image]